# NFS mount at boot with autofs on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: boot, systemd, nfs, init.d, autofs

I'm trying to configure my RPi with **Raspbian Jessie** to use `autofs` to mount **at boot** a NFS share from my QNAP NAS.

The manual mount with

`mount -v -t nfs server://share /mnt/share`

works and also the `autofs` service works if I **manually start it** with

`sudo service autofs start`

**after** starting also `rpcbind` and `nfs-common` services first.

Now I want that all the 3 services involved (`rpcbind`, `nfs-common` and `autofs`) start automatically at boot.

Since Raspbian Jessie uses `systemd`, what should I do to add to the boot the `rpcbind` and `nfs-common` services, that should start **before** `autofs`?

Should I use `init.d` and so

`sudo update-rc.d rpcbind enable`

`sudo update-rc.d nfs-common enable`

or do I have to create a `systemd` unit file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this solution. I used

```
sudo update-rc.d rpcbind enable
```

and

```
sudo update-rc.d nfs-common enable
```

to enable `rpcbind` and `nfs-commond` to start at boot, but only `nfs-common` starts correctly while `rpcbind` not.

So I found a workaround for `rpcbind` by adding

```
service rpcbind start
```

inside the `/etc/rc.local` script. I know it's not the proper way... but it works.

If anyone had any better suggestions, it is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Debian, but Ubuntu has a bug with that right now.

The current workaround is to add "x-systemd.automount" in the options section of the fstab line.

See bug [1515446](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1515446).

Comment: I don't want to use `fstab` and so I have no fstab line. I need to understand how to correctly start at boot rpc`rpcbind` and `nfs-common`, before `autofs`.